2 Nginx Reverse Proxy Manager after each other
I would like to connect two reverse proxies in Docker (jc21/nginx-proxy-manager) one behind the other. The connection between these should run via https.
The connection between the two via http works without any problems.
However, as soon as I select https as the protocol on the first proxy, I get (502 Bad Gateway) as the result.
The problem doesn't seem to be with the SSL certificate, as I don't get any errors with
curl -v --resolve temp.domain.com:8044:10.10.73.70 https://temp.domain.com:8044.


I didn't find the error. I just used zoraxy as an alternative
